# ¿Cómo puedo denotar que alguien bostezó de aburrimiento?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, interjecciones

Quiero enfatizar la siguiente frase:

> Me voy a dormir

Así que pensé usar **ah**, ya que fonéticamente fue lo que primero se me ocurrió. Quedando

> ¡Ah! Me voy a dormir

Pero una visita rápida al diccionario

> [ah](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1GNbcOe)
>
> 1. interj. U. para denotar pena, admiración, sorpresa o sentimientos similares.
> 2. interj. Am. U. para interrogar.

¿Qué interjección puedo usar para describir aburrimiento?

Comment: La más cercana que conozco. Uh. http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=b1OpfUP 1. interj. U. para denotar desilusión o desdén.

Comment: .......Zzzzzzzz.

Comment: Se me ocurre que podrías usar: `Bueno, me voy a dormir` o `En fin, me voy a dormir`, realmente las palabras *bueno* y *en fin*, no denotan sorpresa,  más bien denotan un tanto de indiferencia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No hay consenso acerca de cuál es la onomatopeya (una palabra que representa un sonido o un fenómeno visual.) del bostezo. Unos dirán que "uah" otros que "ouahh" y otros que "oooouaahhhh". Prueba a buscar en Google "[onomatopeya bostezo](https://www.google.com/search?q=onomatopeya%20bostezo&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)" y verás como cada cual propone lo que le parece, a diferencia de lo que puede pasar con la onomatopeya de un estornudo, por ejemplo, donde casi todo el mundo dirá que suena de la misma manera.

Podrías usar el propio verbo `bostezar` dependiendo de cómo lo narres:

> "Me voy a dormir" *bostezó* Diego
>
> "Me voy a dormir" dije con un *bostezo*

De la manera en lo que lo necesitas, debes de hecho "saltarte las reglas" pues las onomatopeyas, para ser fieles al sonido que intentan representar no se atan a normas. Por ejemplo, si quiero representar que hay una mosca volando puedo usar "Bzzzzz" o "Bzzzzzzzzz". El número de zetas va a dar igual para transmitir el mensaje. Luego, dentro del texto, a las onomatopeyas se las trata como al resto de las palabras, sin necesidad de ponerlas entrecomilladas ni nada similar (salvo que estén dentro de una cita).

Answer (score 0):

Seguí con las búsqueda y [encontré uf](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjecci%C3%B3n)

Validado con la RAE

> [uf](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b0zBgLN)
>
> 1. interj. U. para denotar cansancio, fastidio o sofocación.
> 2. interj. Indica repugnancia.

Aunque no es lo que busco puede que a alguien le sirva para cansancio.

Comment: También hay *uy*.